# Wikipedia metadata dump?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I need metadata for wikipedia articles (title, views, time edited, categories, etc.).

I was looking through the dumps at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20221201/ and there's so many that I'm not sure what to choose. I don't need a full dump because I don't need the page contents, so is there one in this I can download that just has the metadata? It's not clear and I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: For how many articles? If it's not many, then you're best of using the API, although you'll need to make a few different calls for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some metadata information on the page information e.g.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=National_Ignition_Facility&action=info

However, the page information does not show the statistics of views. You can find that information at another location:

https://pageviews.wmcloud.org/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&redirects=0&range=latest-20&pages=National_Ignition_Facility

Another approach could be in the page table of the database dump available at

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/What%27s_available_for_download#Database_tables